# Duplicate vowels in string

Tags: java, string, char

I have to write a method that takes in a String and returns a new 
string that replaces every vowel with two occurrences of 
that vowel.

For example: "hello" would return "heelloo"

I've experimented with my code for hours but I am not getting anything done. Here is my code:

```
public static String doubleVowel(String str)
{ 
String result = str;
for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
{
    if((str.charAt(i) == 'a') || 
    (str.charAt(i) == 'e')  ||
    (str.charAt(i) == 'i') || 
    (str.charAt(i) == 'o') ||
    (str.charAt(i) == 'u')) 
    {
        result = result.substring(0, i + 1) + Character.toString(result.charAt(i)) 
        + result.substring(i + 1, result.length());
        i++;
    }
}          
return result;
}
```

When the input is "hello", the output is "heelllo"
When the input is "computer" the output is "coomppuuter"
When the input is "sweet" the output is "sweeet"

I have racked my brain but to no avail. What is causing the bug in the program, and is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Some hints: add print statements for the various steps; or simply run a debugger. And hopefully not discouraging you: there are much simpler ways to get this done. Hint: there is not much point in assigning the input to result, to then call substring all over the place on result. That is absolutely not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're over-complicating things. Instead of using substrings, just construct a result string by appending each character, or appending it twice if it's a vowel:

```
public static String doubleVowel(String str) { 
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char ch = str.charAt(i);
        result.append(ch);
        if (ch == 'a' || 
            ch == 'e' ||
            ch == 'i' || 
            ch == 'o' ||
            ch == 'u') {
            result.append(ch); // second append for vowels
    {
    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! So from what I am seeing, Stringbuilder allows you to connect characters together and create a string yourself?

Comment: @BigBoss `StringBuilder` is probably the most convenient way to construct strings dynamically, not only from characters, but also from numeric primitives, other strings, and even other objects. Check out [Oracle's tutorial about it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html) for additional details.

Answer (score 2):

Use regex:

```
return str.replaceAll("[aeiou]", "$0$0")
```

Comment: I think you need a `([aeiou])`

Comment: @PeterLawrey, I actually did that initially (with `$1$1`), but I realized it was unnecessary.

Comment: I understand what this line of code does, but how? I haven't learned about RegEx yet.

Comment: Actually, @YassinHajaj I like your answer a lot, because it's short and simple, it doesn't require regular expressions, and it's very easy to understand.  I wish you hadn't deleted it.

Comment: @DavidWallace Here it is again :) Thank you for the support

Answer (score 2):

You are testing the character at the *i*th position in **str** but then manipulate it in **result**. Until **result** is updated for the first time it is indeed equal to **str**, but from then on - the two are no longer in sync...

EDIT:

Like others have pointed out - there are better ways to do this. However the question was what the bug in the program was, not what the best way to accomplish this task is :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use replace?

```
public static String doubleVowel (String word) {
    return word.replace("a", "aa")
               .replace("e", "ee")
               .replace("i", "ii")
               .replace("o", "oo")
               .replace("u", "uu");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your basic problem is that you are using the same indexing for `str` and `result` even though after you duplicate one letter,these two strings will have different sizes and you can't use the same index any more.

It would be much simpler to build up a new StringBuilder so you don't need to maintain a second index.

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuidler();
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    char ch = str.charAt(i);
    result.append(ch); // always add the char
    if ("aeiouAEIOU".indexOf(ch) >= 0)
        result.append(ch); // add it again.
}
return result.toString();
```

This is where using a debugger would help you understand what your program is doing.

Answer (score 0):

You check the initial String.
Working only with result right after the assignment should work.